# ¿Cómo puedo crear una llave primaria de cadena, usando identity para autoincrementarla?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Debo realizar un sistema gestor de base de datos, y estaba pensando en realizar llaves primarias usando identity, además de eso, me gustaría que antes de la enumeración, tuviera un prefijo, por ejemplo: "C - 002".

Comment: Aunque interesante, no convendria que dejaras el identity como solo numerico, para tener ese tipo de claves, y si queres agregar prefijos, lo hicieras en otro campo, tal vez con un trigger? para que usarias esos campos asi?

Comment: verifica usuando campos `uniqueidentifier`, los cuales puedes setear con la función `newid()`, esto te da un identificador de tipo `5E315E7B-6C02-3932-8CDF-C0B582D3634C`

Answer (score 1):

aunque esto te puede representar un problema de rendimiento, puedes hacerlo usando una columna calculada que se alimente de una que sea autoincremento, así te ahorras validaciones que el propio motor puede hacer de manera autónoma.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TablaEjemplo
    (
    IDNumerico int NOT NULL,
    IDTexto  AS 'C-'+convert(varchar(10), IDNumerico),
    Texto varchar(50) NOT NULL
    )  ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TablaEjemplo ADD CONSTRAINT
    PK_Table_1 PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    IDTexto
    ) WITH( STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.TablaEjemploSET (LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE)
GO
```

Comment: Entiendo que deberías definir `IDTexto`  como `PERSISTED NOT NULL`, para que lo puedas usar como `PRIMARY KEY`

Comment: @Patricio como está el script funciona al 100%

Comment: Una clave primaria que permite NULL?  Un índice sobre una columna calculada que no fue persistido? Qué versión de SQL server estás usando?

Comment: Inmediatamente te hace alter, realiza eso que dices... Prueba el script y compruébalo. MSSQL 2017

Comment: Elena, mi comentario apunta a mejorar tu respuesta que es la apropiada en cuanto a lo que se debe hacer, pero que no funciona en la práctica al menos en 2012/2016 y 2017 mediante http://www.sqlfiddle.com. Por que? por los motivos antes mencionados, una clave primaria sobre un campo nuleable y un índice sobre una columna calculada. la solución es tan simple como: `IDTexto AS 'C-'+convert(varchar(10), IDNumerico) PERSISTED NOT NULL`. Saludos

Comment: En ese mismo sentido y para no dejar dudas al respecto, te pedí que generaras el código en una instancia real de MSSQL y vieras el resultado del mismo. Lastimosamente no puedo darte la razón cuando ese código fue escrito, probado y ejecutado desde el mismo motor de SQL en su modo gráfico y luego autogenerando el script a través del mismo motor. 
La página desde la cual probaste está ejecutando el código de una y en SQL se ejecutaría cada bloque separado por la cláusula "GO"

Comment: Elena: tu código lo copié y pegué en instancias reales de 2012/2016 y en un fiddle para 2017, tu código no funciona por las razones que ya te he comentado, además de tener un error tipográfico que no viene al caso.  El problema en sí no es la tabla sino lo índices.